# Jaccard Distance

Tags: algorithm, distance

I have this problem in calculating Jaccard Distance for Sets (Bit-Vectors):

p1 = 10111;

p2 = 10011.

Size of intersection = 3; (How could we find it out?)

Size of union = 4,  (How could we find it out?)

Jaccard similarity = (intersection/union) = 3/4.

Jaccard Distance = 1 – (Jaccard similarity) = (1-3/4) = 1/4.

But I don't understand how could we find out the **"intersection"** and **"union"** of the two vectors.

Please help me.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Size of intersection = 3; (How could we find it out?)

Amount of set bits of `p1&p2 = 10011`

> Size of union = 4, (How could we find it out?)

Amount of set bits of `p1|p2 = 10111`

Vector here means binary array where i-th bit means does i-th element present in this set.

Comment: Note: if you don't know how to compute number of `1` bits, read this: http://www-graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive

Comment: Many many many thanks for all of you guys, I appreciate your help. :D

Answer (score 4):

If p1 = 10111 and p2 = 10011,

The total number of each combination attributes for p1 and p2:

- M11 = total number of attributes where p1 & p2 have a value 1,
- M01 = total number of attributes where p1 has a value 0 & p2 has a value 1,
- M10 = total number of attributes where p1 has a value 1 & p2 has a value 0,
- M00 = total number of attributes where p1 & p2 have a value 0.

Jaccard similarity coefficient = J = intersection/union = M11/(M01 + M10 + M11) = 3 / (0 + 1 + 3) = 3/4,

Jaccard distance = J' = 1 - J = 1 - 3/4 = 1/4,
Or J' = 1 - (M11/(M01 + M10 + M11)) = (M01 + M10)/(M01 + M10 + M11) = (0 + 1)/(0 + 1 + 3) = 1/4

Comment: Why is M00 not included in the denominator? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43518507/why-dont-we-include-0-matches-while-calculating-jaccard-distance-between-binary