# Jaccard distance - union and intersection of lists

Tags: python, union, intersection

I am implementing hierarchical clustering using Jaccard distance. The transactions for which I am trying to find Jaccard are represented in binary. For eg.:

`t1=['0','1','1','0','1']`

`t2=['1','0','1','0','0']`.

I looked at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378658/jaccard-distance), which is very similar to what I want, but I am not getting the right answer.

Basically this is what I am looking for:
1. find intersection and union for the above 2 lists.

I have tried the below apart from looking at numerous other online resources:

```
1. s1=sets.Set(['0','1','1','0','1'])
   s2=sets.Set(['1','0','1','0','0'])  
2. s1.intersection(s2)  ---> Set(['1', '0'])  
   s1.union(s2)         ---> Set(['1', '0'])  
3. Set(s1) & Set(s2)      ---> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Set' and 'Set'

   Set(s1) | Set(s2)
```

Please guide me.

Thanks.

Comment: a and b are the transactions as well. i have edited my question now to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said:

```
s1=sets.Set(['0','1','1','0','1'])
```

Let's check s1:

```
print s1
---->Set(['1', '0'])
```

*sets* module provides classes for constructing and manipulating unordered collections of **unique** elements. So, your s1 and s2 are actually the same.

Comment: But if you see the positions of the 0's and 1's, they are not the same. I want the intersection of the 2 sets (s1 and s2) to be 1/5 (because there is a "1" at position 3 for both) and the union to be 4/5 (there are 4 1's when we combine the 2 sets)

Comment: I couldn't find out a way to solve this using sets, but I wrote a function that checks every field in the list.

Comment: @Sarvavyapi , Elements of the set are different because of the index, so maybe you can can form a set with index of '1's.