# Why don't we include 0 matches while calculating jaccard distance between binary numbers?

Tags: algorithm, distance

I am working on a program based on Jaccard Distance, and I need to calculate the Jaccard Distance between two binary bit vectors. I came across the following on the net:

```
 If p1 = 10111 and p2 = 10011,

 The total number of each combination attributes for p1 and p2:

 M11 = total number of attributes where p1 & p2 have a value 1,
 M01 = total number of attributes where p1 has a value 0 & p2 has a value 1,
 M10 = total number of attributes where p1 has a value 1 & p2 has a value 0,
 M00 = total number of attributes where p1 & p2 have a value 0.
 Jaccard similarity coefficient = J = 
 intersection/union = M11/(M01 + M10 + M11) 
 = 3 / (0 + 1 + 3) = 3/4,

 Jaccard distance = J' = 1 - J = 1 - 3/4 = 1/4, 
 Or J' = 1 - (M11/(M01 + M10 + M11)) = (M01 + M10)/(M01 + M10 + M11)
 = (0 + 1)/(0 + 1 + 3) = 1/4
```

Now, while calculating the coefficient, why was "M00" not included in the denominator? Can anyone please explain?

Comment: You can come across this snippet not only on the net, but also right here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19969874/14955

Answer (score 1):

Jaccard coefficient is a measure of asymmetric binary attributes,f.e., a scenario where the presence of an item is more important than its absence.

Since M00 deals only with absence, we do not consider it while calculating Jaccard coeffecient.

For example, while checking for the presence/absence of a disease, the presence of the disease is the more significant outcome.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The Jacquard index of A and B is |A∩B|/|A∪B| = |A∩B|/(|A| + |B| - |A∩B|).

We have: |A∩B| = M11, |A| = M11 + M10, |B| = M11 + M01.

So |A∩B|/(|A| + |B| - |A∩B|) = M11 / (M11 + M10 + M11 + M01 - M11) = M11 / (M10 + M01 + M11).

This Venn diagram may help:
[image]

Comment: I am sorry but I couldn't understand this: 
             |A| = M11 + M10, |B| = M11 + M01
Can you please explain how you arrived at this?

Comment: M11 is the number of bits that appear in A and B. M10 is the number of bits that appear in A but don't appear in B. Their sum is what?

Comment: Drawing venn diagrams may help if you're stuck thinking algebraically or combinatorially.

Comment: Why wasn't M00 included in the intersection of A and B (labelled as M11), since that does represent the case where both A and B have the same elements. Or does the formula inherently not contain M00 case?

Comment: How are you defining the Jaccard Index between the two bit vectors? The usual idea would be to treat the bitvector as representing a set of integers, where `i` is in the set if the `i`th bit is set. But it seems like you are using a different definition -- perhaps you could describe more precisely what definition you're using?

Comment: ... and with the usual definition, M00 isn't important because the 0 bits represent the absence of something in the set rather than the presence.